# What's error in this program, I get Force close for this

Tags: android

I Get force close when executed on Android emulator. I can't figure out the error. Here is code of Main Activity SimpleJokeList.java

```
    package edu.calpoly.android.lab2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleJokeList extends Activity {

    /** Contains the list Jokes the Activity will present to the user **/
    protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrJokeList;

    /**
     * LinearLayout used for maintaining a list of Views that each display Jokes
     **/
    protected LinearLayout m_vwJokeLayout;

    /**
     * EditText used for entering text for a new Joke to be added to
     * m_arrJokeList.
     **/
    protected EditText m_vwJokeEditText;

    /**
     * Button used for creating and adding a new Joke to m_arrJokeList using the
     * text entered in m_vwJokeEditText.
     **/
    protected Button m_vwJokeButton;

    /**
     * Background Color values used for alternating between light and dark rows
     * of Jokes.  
     */
    protected int m_nDarkColor;
    protected int m_nLightColor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initLayout();
        // TODO
        String[] jokestring=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jokeList);    
        for(String str : jokestring) {
                addJoke(str);
            }
        }

    /**
     * Method used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the Layout
     * for this Activity. 
     */
    protected void initLayout() {
        // TODO
        m_vwJokeLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        m_vwJokeLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ScrollView Sv=new ScrollView(this);
        Sv.addView(m_vwJokeLayout);
        setContentView(Sv);


    }

    /**
     * Method used to encapsulate the code that initializes and sets the Event
     * Listeners which will respond to requests to "Add" a new Joke to the 
     * list. 
     */
    protected void initAddJokeListeners() {
        // TODO
    }

    /**
     * Method used for encapsulating the logic necessary to properly initialize
     * a new joke, add it to m_arrJokeList, and display it on screen.
     * 
     * @param strJoke
     *            A string containing the text of the Joke to add.
     */
    protected void addJoke(String strJoke) {
        // TODO
        Joke j=new Joke(strJoke);
        m_arrJokeList.add(j);
        TextView TV=new TextView(this);
        m_vwJokeLayout.addView(TV);
        TV.setText(strJoke);
    }
}
```

Here is code of Joke.java

```
   package edu.calpoly.android.lab2;
public class Joke {
    public static final int UNRATED = 0;
    public static final int LIKE = 1;
    public static final int DISLIKE = 2;
    private String m_strJoke;
    private int m_nRating;
    public Joke() {
        //TODO
        m_strJoke="";
        m_nRating=UNRATED;
    }
    public Joke(String strJoke) {
        //TODO
        m_strJoke=strJoke;
        m_nRating=UNRATED;
    }
    public Joke(String strJoke, int nRating) {
        //TODO
        m_strJoke=strJoke;
        m_nRating=nRating;
    }
    public String getJoke() {
        //TODO
        return m_strJoke;
    }
    public void setJoke(String mstrJoke) {
        //TODO
        m_strJoke=mstrJoke;
    }
    public int getRating() {
        //TODO
        return m_nRating;
    }
    public void setRating(int rating) {
        //TODO
        m_nRating=rating;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //TODO
        return m_strJoke;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //TODO
        boolean ret=false;
        if(obj!=null)
        {
            if(obj.getClass()==Joke.class)
                if(obj.toString().equals(this.m_strJoke))
                    ret=true;
        }
        else
            ret=false;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

Here is Code of Manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="edu.calpoly.android.lab2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <activity android:name=".SimpleJokeList"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
                     android:targetPackage="edu.calpoly.android.lab2"
                     android:label="Tests for Api Demos."/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please format your question correctly so it's readable.  Make sure code blocks are indented with four spaces.  You can select a block of text and click the "{}" button to do this.

Comment: Thanks for reply...Formatted correctly..Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing m_arrJokeList

try

```
 protected ArrayList<Joke> m_arrJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke> ();
```

Note: Since you are overriding `equals` method in the `Joke` class, you should override the `hashCode` method aswell

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Comment: Thank you....My problem is solved..One more question..Does every Object declaration must be initialized in Java? Any resources?

Comment: @andyfan Correct, Except for value-type fields, which get initialized to their default automatically. http://tinyurl.com/66vt58b :-)

Comment: About overriding equals & hasCode in Java

Comment: @andyfan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing m_arrJokeList.

Android App Course. Lab 2 ...

In the public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) method:

Notice the  super.onCreate(savedInstance)  call. This is crucial, never forget to make this call. If you don't your Activity won't work.

Make a call to this.getResources() , which will return a Resources object.
The Resources class provides an interface for retrieving resources by their resourceID.

resourceID's can be found in the static R class, under their respective resource subclasses (which are named after their resource type), under the name given to them in the resource file: R.array.jokeList

**Create an instance of the Joke ArrayList.**

```
m_arrJokeList = new ArrayList<Joke>();
```